# Child thread processes event raised by Parent

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

What I am trying to achieve is the same as the title. In my problem, I have a list of data in my main thread, I want to have the main thread fire an event that can be handled by the child thread to consume the list of data. Is there anyway to do it in C#?

The approach that first comes to my mind is to have the child thread constantly check the list of data. But I think by getting the main thread notifying the child thread, I can save the overhead of having a child thread constantly running in the background.

Comment: [Synchronization Primitives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964.aspx)

Comment: Are you suggesting using signaling mechanism? @14V

Comment: Use blocking collection, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx, which you add to in the parent-thread, and read from in the child-threads.

Comment: You can scale to more than one consuming thread using TPL DataFlow. Is it important to handle messages in the same order as they are posted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should probably use the producer-consumer pattern here. The parent thread will act as the producer and the child thread will act as the consumer. The parent will *produce* the data and publish it in such a manner that the child will be notified (without having to poll for it) so that it can *consume* it. Fortunately, .NET makes this easy with the `BlockingCollection` class. Here is what your code might look like.

```
class Producer
{
  private BlockingCollection<YourData> queue;

  public Producer(BlockingCollection<YourData> q)
  {
    queue = q;
  }

  public void GenerateItems()
  {
    while (...)
    {
      YourData item = GenerateItem();
      queue.Add(item);
    }
  }
}

class Consumer
{
  public Consumer(BlockingCollection<YourData> queue)
  {
    Task.Factory.StartNew(
      () =>
      {
        foreach (YourData item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
          ProcessItem(item);
        }
      ), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
  }

  private void ProcessItem(YourData item)
  {
    // Add logic to process each data item here.
  }

}
```

So we have a `Producer` class that generates data items and adds them to the `BlockingCollection` and a `Consumer` class that removes those data items as they become available. `GetConsumingEnumerable` behaves like `Take` in that it puts the caller into an idle state if there is nothing in the queue. So basically the calling thread is not doing any kind of busy polling (at least not in the trivial sense) so it is resource friendly.

Here is an example of how this is all glued together.

```
public static void Main()
{
  var queue = new BlockingCollection<YourData>();
  var producer = new Producer(queue);
  var consumer = new Consumer(queue);
  producer.GenerateItems();
}
```

You can use the [task cancellation mechanisms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) to get the `GetConsumingEnumerable` enumerator to pop out if want to add in graceful termination. I have not shown how this can be here, but it is not terribly difficult and there are plenty of examples already out there.

Comment: +1 `BlockingCollection` handles graceful termination quite well with the [GetConsumingEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) function. See example at http://blog.mischel.com/2013/07/18/simple-multithreading-part-2/. Also, the `Take` methods all have overloads that support a `CancellationToken`. So there's no need for a `while(true)` and such. I think your answer would be more clear if you dispensed with `ProducerConsumerQueue` class and just used `BlockingCollection` throughout.

Comment: @JimMischel: Agreed. The `ProducerConsumerQueue` bit probably distracts from the salient points and, of course, is totally unnecessary anyway.

Comment: This is a clear explaination and neat example of what I can really use to take care of the problem I am asking. I am gonna try it out. I really appreciate your help @Brian Gideon

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using `ActionBlock` from [TPL DataFlow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) - especially if there is no requirement to process messages sequentially. As a bonus no need to manage consumer thread(s) in your code.

Here is an example:

```
 // Create an ActionBlock that performs some work. 
 var workerBlock = new ActionBlock<MessageData>(

  data=>
     {
         DoWork(data); // method consuming data
     },

  // Specify a maximum degree of parallelism. 
  new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
  {
     MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism
  });

// Post messageCount messages to the queue
for (int i = 0; i < messageCount; i++)
 {
   var messageData = new MessageData();
   workerBlock.Post(messageData);
 }

 // Signal that Producer has no more data to send
 workerBlock.Complete();

 // Wait for all messages to propagate through the network.
 workerBlock.Completion.Wait();
```

Comment: +1: Even if the OP wanted to process the message sequentially there still should be a way to do it with the data flow blocks. Perhaps by using the `SendAsync` method on the block and then opting out of the parallelism.

Comment: There is no point where the producer will complete posting message in my scenario. Instead, message will be continually placed in the queue by the producer, and the consumer needs to process messages in the queue regularly. Thereby, I will go with the BlockCollection approach, but I do thank you for your kind suggestion.

Comment: @liudaisuda: Be aware that BlockingCollection also needs to be "completed" before program shuts down to allow consumer exit the waiting loop.

Comment: @alexm: Thanks for pointing that out. I believe it is an important clue why my program behaved like sitting in an infinite loop. I had my producer thread add items to the Blocking Collection and the consumer as a child thread of the producer. Do you think it is feasible to get it work. I am asking this because it seems like the producer needs to complete using the blockcollection and shuts down itself before the consumer can actually process the blockcollection,

Comment: @alexm: By the way, I couldn't any way to set the producer status to  to "completed". Is is that the producer program needs to be shut down to set it completed?

Comment: BlockingCollection has CompleteAdding() method serves as a signal for consumer to exit the loop, e.g. when closing the program.

Answer (score 1):

The ObservableCollection template class might be the solution for your problem:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

> Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when
>   items get added, removed, or when the whole list is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach would be for your main thread to simply spawn a thread pool thread with a copy of the data, when the main thread is ready for the data to be consumed. No need to to signal; no need to have a background thread already running.

Comment: Your solution is quite applicable in my case because my producer, so to speak, will be adding data into the queue constantly. Thus, there is no such a point where the data is ready for consumption. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Ah. When you said "notifying the child thread" I had assumed there was such a point.